# eclipse上でTomcat起動時に、「重大: フィルタ EncodeFilter の起動中の例外です 」というエラーが出力される

Tags: java

現在[こちらのサイト](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0807/31/news129_4.html)を参考に実装を行っているのですが、
「重大: フィルタ EncodeFilter の起動中の例外です （java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: filters. SetCharacterEncodingFilter）」というエラーが出力されてしまいます。

おそらくSetCharacterEncodingFilter.javaというファイルをfiltersフォルダに入れているのですが、それが今回のエラーの原因だと予想しています。

filterの設定は

```js
<filter-name>EncodeFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>Shift_JIS</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>EncodeFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

です。

参考にしているサイト通りに実装しているはずなので、原因が掴めません。
解決方法の分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

またhttp://サーバのIPアドレス:8080/によるtomcatの起動確認を出来ております。

Comment: java8 にしたら治ったとの事ですが、そうであれば close して下さい。

Comment: 申し訳ありありません、治っていませんでした

Comment: ソースフォルダに `filters/SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java` があって、ビルド対象になっているでしょうか？おそらくこれが無いんだと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

回答ではありませんが、原因を調査していきましょうか。

まずエラーですが「java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: filters. SetCharacterEncodingFilter」です。
Javaがjavaファイルをコンパイルしてclassファイルを作成するのはご存知ですね？
今、エラーとしてはjavaファイルではなくclassファイルを見つけられず、filters. SetCharacterEncodingFilterクラスを使えない状態です。

filtersフォルダ（つまりパッケージ）にSetCharacterEncodingFilter.javaが入っていることは確認されたということですが、classファイルはどうでしょうか。
上記のサイトのとおりに設定されたならHello/WEB-INF/classesフォルダ以下にclassファイル群があります（図13より）。
Hello/WEB-INF/classesフォルダにfiltersフォルダがあり、SetCharacterEncodingFilter.classファイルがありますでしょうか？

もしなければEclipseにてコンパイルし、classファイルを作成する必要があります（メニューのプロジェクト -> クリーンなどで）。
もしあれば、あとは/TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xmlでの`<Context path="/hello" docBase="Helloプロジェクトの位置" />`が本当に今作業しているHelloプロジェクトの位置かどうかだけだと思われます。

Comment: SetCharacterEncodingFilter.classは存在しませんでした。
ファイルを作成したところうまく動作しました。
ありがとうございます。